# Postgres error on partitioned table (ERROR 42703 attribute 4 of type X has been dropped)

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm attaching a partition to one of my partitioned tables and I'm getting an error I don't understand.

This is how I created my partition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_201906_partition (LIKE my_table_000000_partition
                                        INCLUDING ALL)
```

This CREATE TABLE worked ok. `my_table_000000_partition` is the default partition of its parent `my_table`.

And this is how I'm trying to attach it to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ATTACH PARTITION my_table_201906_partition 
  FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-06-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2019-07-01 00:00:00+00');
```

The full error is:

```
INFO:  00000: partition constraint for table "my_table_201906_partition" is implied by existing constraints
LOCATION:  QueuePartitionConstraintValidation, tablecmds.c:14540
ERROR:  42703: attribute 4 of type my_table_000000_partition has been dropped
LOCATION:  CheckVarSlotCompatibility, execExprInterp.c:1880
Time: 10.571 ms
```

Any idea what the error can mean and how to solve it?

## Edit:

### Result of query suggested by amil

This is the query requested by @amil:

```
select attrelid::regclass, attnum, attname 
    from pg_attribute
    where attrelid in ('my_table'::regclass::oid, 
                       'my_table_000000_partition'::regclass::oid)
      and attnum > 0;
```

In the following results I mangled the field names, but I took care of calling `some_field_1` to the same field of both tables. Field `my_timestamp` is the field I'm using for range partitioning.

```
           attrelid            | attnum |           attname            
-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------
 my_table_000000_partition     |      1 | id
 my_table_000000_partition     |      2 | cust_id
 my_table_000000_partition     |      3 | some_field_1
 my_table_000000_partition     |      4 | ........pg.dropped.4........
 my_table_000000_partition     |      5 | my_timestamp
 my_table_000000_partition     |      6 | ........pg.dropped.6........
 my_table_000000_partition     |      7 | some_field_2
 my_table_000000_partition     |      8 | some_field_3
 my_table_000000_partition     |      9 | some_field_4
 my_table_000000_partition     |     10 | some_field_5
 my_table_000000_partition     |     11 | some_field_6
 my_table_000000_partition     |     12 | some_field_7
 my_table_000000_partition     |     13 | some_field_8
 my_table_000000_partition     |     14 | some_field_9
 my_table_000000_partition     |     15 | some_field_10
 my_table_000000_partition     |     16 | some_field_11
 my_table                      |      1 | id
 my_table                      |      2 | cust_id
 my_table                      |      3 | some_field_1
 my_table                      |      4 | my_timestamp
 my_table                      |      5 | some_field_2
 my_table                      |      6 | some_field_3
 my_table                      |      7 | some_field_4
 my_table                      |      8 | some_field_5
 my_table                      |      9 | some_field_6
 my_table                      |     10 | some_field_7
 my_table                      |     11 | some_field_8
 my_table                      |     12 | some_field_9
 my_table                      |     13 | some_field_10
 my_table                      |     14 | some_field_11
(30 rows)
```

Comment: In case it gives any clues, "attribute" in Postgres internal terminology means "column".

Comment: This is an internal system error that you, as a user, are not supposed to see.  So, it basically means that you're hitting some bug that manifests through a sequence of DDL actions that has caused the "dropped attribute" to be seen at all.

Can you please share the result of executing the following query (returns the internal state of the attributes of the parent table and the default partition)?

`select attrelid::regclass, attnum, attname from pg_attribute where attrelid in ('my_table'::regclass::oid, 'my_table_000000_partition'::regclass::oid) and attnum > 0;`

Comment: Did you ever drop a column of `my_table_000000_partition`? Does the error still manifest if you omit the `INCLUDING ALL` when you create the partition?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem. Please try to come up with a reproducible test case.

Comment: @amil I added the results of the query you requested.

Comment: So, according to the results of the query @amil requested, there are 2 dropped columns that are visible, I don't know under what cases postgres does that, may it be related to this table being "too large"? it has 139.225.905 rows, 15GiB in my Dev environment. As a vacuum full rewrites the table, it should fix the issue, right? Any other alternative as in production it's 273GiB?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I checked my DB migrations history and found there used to be 2 columns there (where it now says `pg.dropped`), some years ago they were dropped. About the `INCLUDING ALL` I get the same error even if I don't include it.

Comment: @MondKin, Thanks for the information I asked for.  I have reproduced the issue locally, and found that there's a bug that causes Postgres to see dropped columns (they should never be seen!).  Also, thanks for reporting to the Postgres mailing list; I'm posting a patch for the bug in a bit.

Comment: Thnks for the patch, @amitlan, I pushed it: https://postgr.es/m/E1hgvyw-0005Ws-Bp@gemulon.postgresql.org

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MondoKin's answer already gives a workaround, but let me add an answer about what the error means and why it's caused in this case.

The error seen here is an internal system error thrown by the Postgres executor when it encounters an expression that's built using invalid metadata about a table's column, which in this case is a column value expression that references a dropped attribute of `my_table_000000_partition`.

In most cases involving such internal consistency checks (almost all of them), users are not supposed to expect errors being thrown by them.  Such internal errors could only result from a corrupted internal state (on-disk or in-memory) or a bug of Postgres', which in this case, turned out to be the latter.

Thankfully, @MondoKin reported this issue to Postgres bugs mailing list.  See this link to the mailing list archive, if interested: https://postgr.es/m/flat/15873-8c61945d6b3ef87c%40postgresql.org

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for providing the bugfix!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to attach my new partition: you need to detach the problematic partition before trying to attach the new partition, then reattaching the problematic partition:

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table_201906_partition (LIKE my_table_000000_partition
                                         INCLUDING ALL);

 ALTER TABLE my_table DETACH PARTITION my_table_000000_partition;

 ALTER TABLE my_table
       ATTACH PARTITION my_table_201906_partition
       FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-06-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2019-07-01 00:00:00+00')

ALTER TABLE my_table ATTACH PARTITION my_table_000000_partition DEFAULT;
```

This way, the old partition's dropped column doesn't get into the way of the `ATTACH PARTITION ... FOR RANGE` command. Which means I don't need to vacuum full the 273GiB table.

**The only issue with this workaround is that you need to do it for every partition that you want to attach (until the bug is solved)**

## Edit:

I thought `VACUUM FULL my_table_000000_partition` would permanently solve the issue by totally removing the "deleted" columns, but no, the error persisted.